# How to generate Image.elf from buildroot?

Tags: elf, buildroot

make menuconfig -> kernel -> Kernel Binary format I have only "uImage, zImage, vmlinux and custom target". there is no option for Image.elf. Is there any way to generate Image.elf ?

What is the difference between vmlinux and Image.elf?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to generate the linux kernel `Image` target (i.e., the target when compiling the linux kernel sources in the normal way from the command line via something like `make -jN Image modules dtbs`). In mainline buildroot the kconfig menu options are seen here:

[image: buildroot menuconfig 1[1]]
[image: buildroot menuconfig 2[2]]

If editing the buildroot configuration file (`.config`) directly, the configuration symbols for the `Image` and `vmlinux` targets are `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_IMAGE` and `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_VMLINUX` respectively.

The `vmlinux` target is the statically linked kernel binary in `ELF` format. This is useful when needing to debug the kernel proper, among other things. The `Image` target is the linux kernel not statically linked and not in `ELF` binary format. In the specific example above, Das U-boot will hand program control to the `Image` binary upon normal platform initialization.

Seeing as how the `Image` kernel binary format option doesn't appear in your buildroot kconfig, you should be able to yield it by selecting the custom target configuration option and manually typing in the ASCII string `Image`. You may also have luck deselecting all the kernel configuration items entirely and starting again fresh with a partial or completely blank configuration set. The above screen shots are taken from a buildroot instantiation that is synchronized to the main development master branch circa the date of this answer.

Comment: `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_IMAGE` is only available if the target architecture is aarch64 (arm64). `Image.elf` can't be built by the kernel build system as far as I know.